# Convert one-hot encoding back to number label

Tags: numpy

I have a series of one-hot encoding vector, say

`np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])`

I want to convert it back to

`np.array(0,1,1,2,3)`

Is there an efficient way of doing without for loop?

Comment: Use `numpy.argmax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Divakar in the comments, NumPy's [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) is the easiest way to get the job done. Notice that you need to pass the function the proper value of parameter `axis`.

```py
In [18]: import numpy as np

In [19]: x = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])

In [20]: np.argmax(x, axis=-1)
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```